# Meaning of "They can have each other"

Tags: idioms

> “Poor Janine,” Holly said, and Veronica caught a mocking look that
>   passed between her  and James. It implied she didn’t really have any
>   sympathy for Janine at all.   “She was really upset,” Veronica said,
>   putting enough ice into her voice to warn Holly  off the topic.  But
>   James and Holly’s covert exchange made her angry.  Good, she thought,
>   they can have each other.

Hi! What does the character mean by "They can have each other"? She's going out with James but she doesn't really like him so she's not jealous.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is "washing her hands" of those two. If they want each other, fine. They can have each other. They can strike up whatever sort of relationship that they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @TRomano's answer...

It also implies that for the same reasons that she is upset with them, they will be a fitting punishment for each other, as in: "*They can go ahead and choke on each other!*"